# Jupyter Notebook: why are custom Mathjax macros not working on file open?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, mathjax

I have added custom.js to ~./jupyter/custom. And here's the beginning of the mathjax config section of my custom.js file:

```
MathJax.Hub.Config({
"tex2jax": {
inlineMath: [ ["$","$"], ["(",")"] ],
displayMath: [ ["$$","$$"], ["[","]"] ],
processEscapes: true,
},
"displayAlign": "center",
"extensions" ["tex2jax.js","TeX/AMSmath.js","TeX/AMSsymbols.js","TeX/color.js","TeX/cancel.js"],
"TeX": {
Macros: {
wes: "\blacksquare",
qes: "\frac{1}{8}",
qd: "\quad",
dq: "\quad\quad",
norm: ["{\lvert#1\rvert}", 1],
```

When I open a notebook that uses these macros, the notebook doesn't appear to recognize these macros:

[image: Notebook not recognizing mathjax custom macro]

But when I refresh the page, the macros are usually recognized and presented as expected. Is there something I can do to get Notebook to recognize the Mathjax macros when a file is opened?

Answer (score 1):

<del>I had the same problem. Even though the code in `custom.js` gets executed, the MathJax seems to ignore it, even though this is [the recommended way](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/tex.html#defining-tex-macros).</del>

Then I stumbled upon the [official documentation on defining TeX macros](http://docs.mathjax.org/en/latest/advanced/extension-writing.html#extension-to-define-tex-macros) and ended up with the following snippet in my `custom.js`:

```
MathJax.Hub.Register.StartupHook("TeX Jax Ready", function () {
  MathJax.InputJax.TeX.Definitions.Add({
    macros: {
      Expecto: ["Macro", "\\mathop{\\mathbb{E}}"]
    }
  });
});
```

**EDIT from the future**: the links above have become obsolete, refer to [this one](https://docs.mathjax.org/en/v2.7-latest/advanced/extension-writing.html#extension-to-define-tex-macros) instead.